# linker command failed: duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I am having this error while running my project. I referred so many answers and did the same but can't resolve this issue.

```
duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
/Users/admin/Downloads/workRepo/SafetraxApp/MAppIOS/build2/Safetrax/Build/Intermediates/Safetrax.build/Debug-iphoneos/Parent App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Reachability.o
Pods/catapush-ios-sdk-pod/CatapushKit/libCatapushLib.a(CLIntReachability.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You are most likely importing Reachability into two or more classes, which is producing a naming collision. Search for imports on it and see if you can remove the duplicate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the Reachability snippet from Apple. Unfortunately, that piece of code and the accompanying constants are being used in several Cocoapods. That's what causes this error. It basically means that the symbol/constant `kReachabilityChangedNotification` has been defined twice in your binary: once in your Application and once in the `CatapushKit` pod.

The easiest way to fix is: Rename the constant in your code. The other option would be to delete the Reachbility code from your app and use the `CLIntReachability` implementation from `CatapushKit`.

Comment: perfect answer @Jens Meder